# Why can't I place a Campus district on certain tiles

Tags: civilization-6

I have following tile setup:

```
        {city}
        /
     {hill A} {mountain}
        \     /
       {hill B} -- {hill C}
         /    \
  {mountain} {rainforest}
```

I want to put Campus district on Hill B and profit from 2 mountains and 1 rainforest but I'm simply not allowed to do so. I own Hill A, Hill B and purchased Hill C but even after that I still can't put a Campus on Hill B.

The Civilopedia entry for the Campus district does not mention any restrictions on the placement, except the adjacency bonuses.

So why am I not allowed to put a Campus on Hill B?

Update - figured it out after I read the list of reasons - Hill B had rainforest and I did not have the tech to clear it.

Comment: Are there any ressources on that tile? Or is it a floodplains tile?

Comment: @MarcBrinkmann no. I'll add a screenshot later. A and C have wine and sheep.

Comment: You aren't at the district limit for the city perhaps?

Comment: @n_palum nope - I can put the district on other tiles, but not on that one. If you are at the limit, then you are not allowed to select the district as a building.

Comment: Hmm weird.. I'm just trying to figuring out why since there are not restrictions other than floodplains and population limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/District_(Civ6)), the limitations are as follows

- Floodplains (unless you're Egypt).
- Strategic/Luxury Resources (Unless it was built before that strategic
  resource was revealed, in which case you're granted access once it is
  researched).
- Antiquity Sites or Shipwrecks before you've excavated them.
- Already existing Wonders/Districts
- Non-Clearable Features (e.g. If you don't have mining you can't build
  a district on a forest).
- Harbor Districts must be adjacent to land.
- Aerodome and Spaceport districts must be on flat land (no hills).
- Aqueducts must be one tile away from both your city center and a
  mountain, river, or lake tile.

It states that you can place districts on bonus resources but they will be removed.

Comment: I think I figured it out - it is because is "Non-Clearable Features". Hill B had a rainforest and I did not have the tech necessary to clear it.